# redux mapDispatchToProps with chained arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can understand the following sample code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todo: state.todos[0]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    destroyTodo: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'DESTROY_TODO'
      })
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

Which when in a component, I can call `this.props.destroyTodo()` so it executes `dispatch(...)` within the function.

This is according to the manual (if it's a function):

> mapDispatchToProps: this parameter can either be a function, or an
>   object.
>
> If it’s a function, it will be called once on component creation. It
>   will receive dispatch as an argument, and should return an object full
>   of functions that use dispatch to dispatch actions.
>
> If it’s an object
>   full of action creators, each action creator will be turned into a
>   prop function that automatically dispatches its action when called.
>   Note: We recommend using this “object shorthand” form.

But I struggle to understand with this existing code which is **working** chained arrow functions (another layer of function):

```
export const createBillingRun = id => dispatch => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `/api/billing/billingtypes/${id}/createrun/`,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(() => dispatch(pollBillingRuns(id)));
};
```

I have converted into tradition syntax here:

```
export const createBillingRun = function(id) {
    return function(dispatch){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: `/api/billing/billingtypes/${id}/createrun/`,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(() => dispatch(pollBillingRuns(id)));
    }
}
```

This function then mapped in the redux `connect`:

```
export default connect(
    {...},
    {
        createBillingRun
    },
)(ThePage);
```

From the above code, `createBillingRun` returns an extra layer of function, so if I execute `createBillingRun(123)`, it will return a function that accepts `dispatch` as a parameter, which is similar to the first example that gets passed into the `connect`. So who is executing the inner function?

Can somebody please help me to understand why the chained arrow functions would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only works if you have Redux Thunk installed. It's a middleware that sees when you're returning a function, passes that function dispatch and calls it.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

export default thunk;
```

Comment: Now I can rest in peace.

Answer (score 1):

When your `mapDispatchToProps` returns an object, "it is assumed to be a Redux action creator." (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Action creators are supposed to return actions, which "are plain JavaScript objects." (https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)

The ability to return a function from an action creator is provided by redux-thunk, so make sure you are applying it as middleware. (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

...

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)(createStore);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a redux noob and for the life of me I couldn't figure out why it worked, but it makes sense now.

Comment: No worries. Keep in mind "If you’re not sure whether you need it, you probably don’t." - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk. Based on your example, I don't seen a clear reason for having it, so keep that in mind :)

Comment: That's existing code... but I presume simply reversing the order of the arrow chain would work without needing the thunk lib?